# lamba functions with different parameters inside a loop

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I have created a small GUI in which I want to create buttons in a loop which are supposed to open a text file. The function to open the textfile stands in another python module which I have included:

```
def openTextEditor(textfile):
"""opens the textfile with path 'textfile' """
    [...]
```

In my actual loop I try to assign different paths to the buttons:

```
for path in foobar:
    print path
    tk.Button(text="EDIT",
              relief="tk.RAISED",
              bg='black',
              fg='white',
              command= lambda: openTextEditor(path) ).grid(row=r, column=c)
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared) I know that I have to use a lamda expression in order to pass a parameter as button command.

However, my console prints different paths to text files:

```
path1
path2
path3
```

while all of my 3 buttons open text file with *path3*. I assume that only the last assignment of the lambda function has effect, but why?

Comment: BTW: I had problems to find an accurate title and so I had problems to find similar questions. I think this problem raised in another form already.

Comment: Duplicate, but can't find it right now. Try `lambda path=path: openTextEditor(path)`

Comment: @tobias_k thanks that worked, should I close it?